# May I delete my internships and short contract works from my CV to avoid the Employment Reference Letter for Canadian Work permit application?

Tags: working-visas, canada

I'm applying for a work visa for as a graduate student in Computer Science for a research project in Canada. They ask several documents two of them are difficult to get :

> **Document: Employment Reference Letter**
>
> You must provide an employment reference letter (an up-to-date
>   reference from current or past employers). If you have had more than
>   two employers in the last two years, please provide a letter from both
>   employers.
>
> Reference letters must be written on company letterhead, show the
>   company's full address and telephone and fax numbers, and be stamped
>   with the company's official seal.
>
> The letter should include all of the following information:
>
> - the specific period of your employment with the company
> - the positions you held during the period of employment and the time spent    in each position
> - full details of your main responsibilities in    each position
> - your total annual salary plus benefits
> - the signature of your immediate supervisor or the personnel officer at    the company
> - a business card of the person signing

I only worked during summers as intern. It has been a year since I quited my last internship and two since I was a contract employee. I only worked three months in each case. One was a contract based work and the other was an internship. This seems quite difficult to pop in, say "hi" and ask them for it ... Can I delete them my CV on the principle that it is internships?

They later ask for the following :

> **Document: Employment Records** :
>
> You must provide proof of work experience
>   for your current job and for each past position you listed. Proof must
>   include a reference letter from your employer and pay stubs, if you
>   have them. The reference letter must:
>
> > be an official document printed on company letterhead
> >        include your name, the company's contact information (address, telephone number and e-mail address), the signature of your immediate
> >        show all positions held while employed at the company
> >        include these details: job title, duties/responsibilities, job status (if current job), the dates you worked for the company, the
> >     number of work hours per week and your annual salary plus benefits.
>
> You must scan all documents for this period of employment and save
>   them as one file. (You must create a separate file for each period of
>   employment.)

And then again in the [Imm1295 E document](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm1295e.pdf)

The problem is that it is mandatory to fill these fields, yet I an about-to-be graduated student and it would facilitate my life not to have to ask my former tutors for these documents. The question that would arise, which is linked with my former question, would be : what should I fill in ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title: No.  You can't lie on your CV to save you having to gather documentation.

You *might* get away with it, but if you get caught you will *definitely* be turned down for your visa.

I suggest writing to your former employers, with some proposed text for them to copy and paste and print out on a company letterhead.  Unless you left on really bad terms, they should be happy to do that.